Could not update simulator linking permissions when trying to open iOS simulator
Did a fresh install of MacOS, Xcode v15, nodejs v22, and create a project using "npx create-expo-app tester --template blank" command. Then straight away cd into the app directory and run "npx expo start", metro server started but when choosing to open simulator, gives me the caution
"Could not update simulator linking permissions ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5A29801D-6F03-4821-BC0D-C4821243D61D/data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.launchservices.schemeapproval.plist'"
Expo GO Never installs on the simulator and the project can never run.
Tried doing everything from reinstalling iOS simulator to granting Xcode, VSCode, and Simulator app the full file system right, nothing works.

Did you find a solution for this? Having the same issue for days now!

The error occurs because the IDE you're using does not have permission to send Apple events to System Events.
To resolve the issue:

Open the settings.
Go to Privacy & Security > Automation.

The IDE you're using should be in the list of apps. If it’s not listed, add it, then permit it to control System Events.

Thanks for the answer. The IDE was already listed under Automation inside Privacy and Security and already been given Permission for System Events.

The problem is with expo caching. After updating xcode and simulator, xcode creates new ids for simulated devices. In some cases expo does not delete cached ids and that's why you get the error. In order to fix it, remove everything from .expo folder. It mostly contains cached information. The folder should be located in your home directory.
so just run the command and everything should work:
sudo rm -rf ~/.expo/*


If your terminal have automation permissions, you just need to reset cache:
sudo rm -Rf node_modules
sudo rm -Rf .expo
// If you prebuild your app
sudo rm -Rf ios
sudo rm -Rf android

npm install or yarn

Then, npx expo start -c or if you prebuilded your app, npx expo prebuild.
It should be working!
